# ArchiveStatus Flag in Mailbox object

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

Normally to get the list of archive mailboxes I use,

```
Get-Mailbox -Archive
```

I recently found that the mailbox object has a flag named 'ArchiveStatus' that either has values Active or None.
When I run

```
Get-Mailbox -Filter {ArchiveStatus -eq 'Active'}
```

the results are different(only some of the mailboxes;though I don't know if it might consist of entirely different mailboxes and hence the question) from those of the previous cmdlets'

So what exactly does the 'ArchiveStatus' flag mean and are there possibilities where the flag might not have been set at all?

Comment: Have you already [read the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123685(v=exchg.160).aspx)?

Comment: @vonPryz I have and It doesn't have anything to say about 'ArchiveStatus' flag!

Answer (score 2):

Per the following article:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4486848/check-status-of-an-archive-mailbox-in-office-365

> You should not use the ArchiveStatus property value to check the
> status of the archive unless this is a cross-premises scenario where
> the primary mailbox is on-premises and the archive mailbox exists in
> Office 365 (that is, cross-premises archive). In all other scenarios,
> you should use both of the following properties to confirm the status
> of the archive:
>
> ArchiveDatabase
> ArchiveGuid

The article goes on to suggest the following code:

```
Get-mailbox UserName |fl archivedatabase,archiveguid
```

And then states that the output resembles the following:

```
ArchiveDatabase             : DatabaseIdParameter
ArchiveGuid                 : GUID
```

Reading between the lines, it sounds like ArchiveStatus is a legacy property that is not reliable in all scenarios for determining the status of mailbox archives. I would probably use something like:

```
Get-Recipient | Where-Object {$null -ne $_.ArchiveDatabase}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to MS Docs ([Set-Mailbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/set-mailbox?view=exchange-ps)), this property is for internal use only, although it has 2 possible values with speaking names - None and Active. 
I'd recommend to search mailboxes with Archive enabled by your first command `Get-Mailbox -Archive`